# How to send an object to array of socket in Java

Tags: java

Example:

```
ArrayList arraySocket=new ArrayList();
...
arraySocket.add(client);
...
for (Object arraySocket1 : arraySocket) {
      DataOutputStream dataToClient = new DataOutputStream(arraySocket1.getOutputStream()); // it's wrong. But i don't know how to correct it.
      dataToClient.writeBytes(cData.getData()+"\n");
}
```

Comment: you mean you have an array of sockets (on the server side) and you want to send an object to over all those sockets ?!

Comment: @QuakeCore Yes, how can i correct it? thanks.

Comment: well cast your arraySocket1 to Socket like this ((Socket)arraySocket1).getOutputStream()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Generics.

```
ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket = new ArrayList<>(); // works in Java 7 and above

ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket = new ArrayList<Socket>(); // for versions 6 and below
```

I have assumed that the type of Object in the List is a `Socket`. Then you need to use the correct type in the for loop:

```
for (Socket arraySocket1 : arraySocket) {
```

Comment: It seems wrong in "DataOutputStream dataToClient = new DataOutputStream(arraySocket1.getOutputStream());". arraySocket1 hasn't "getOutputStream" method... Can you show me another way ? thanks.

Comment: You need to tell us where the getOutputStream method defined. I have guessed that you have a Socket class that has this method, but until we know what the type of the object you are working with is, then we are all just guessing. Nevertheless I have updated my answer assuming the Socket is the correct type.

Comment: i have correted it. arraySocket should use "set method", it will return socket type, after that can be used  with getOutputStream.  arraySocket.set(i, socket).getOutputStream. :))

Comment: If one of these answers helped you should accept it. Otherwise add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is a raw type, you need to parametrize it.

I suppose you want to do the following :

```
ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

Here `arraySocket` is an ArrayList of `Socket`s (i.e. the arraylist contains only elements of type `Socket`).

To send something over an outputstream you can do the following in your for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySocket.size(); i++) {
      DataOutputStream dataToClient = new DataOutputStream(arraySocket.get(i).getOutputStream()); // Get the i'th outputstream
      dataToClient.writeBytes(...); // Write your data
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but how can i do to send something to those sockets when arraySocket1 hasn't getOutputStream method..?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket=new ArrayList<>();
    //... arraySocket.add(socket);...
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySocket.size(); i++){
        DataOutputStream dataToClient = new DataOutputStream(arraySocket.get(i).getOutputStream()); // Get the i'th outputstream
        dataToClient.writeBytes(...); // Write your data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to use Generics, like this:

```
ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

Now you can loop over the Sockets in the array with this piece of code:

```
for(Socket socket: arraySocket){
   DataOutputStream dataOutput newDataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//write data with the dataOuput.
}
```

But there will be a problem when you want to write data multiple times, if you create 2 output streams from 1 socket and they write at the same time it will generate an exception, so it is better create a second array list with all the sockets output streams (or a map) and write to those.

example:

```
//the array list with sockets
ArrayList<Socket> arraySocket = new ArrayList<Socket>();

ArrayList<OutputStream> outputStreams = new ArrayList<OutputStream>();

//save the output streams
for(Socket socket: arraySocket){
    outputStreams.add(socket.getOutputStream);
}


//to write to the sockets use this
for(OutputStream output: outputStreams){
     //write data to the output.
}
```